# How to upload images to S3 using django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image from the django admin interface to AWS S3.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' % (AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'kti.storages.S3Storage'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFUALT_ACL = None

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, 'mysite/static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

This is what I have in my settings.py and when I upload an image the URL it gets is perfectly fine when I checked it but the image isn't uploaded in S3. I followed a couple of tutorials such as [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/), but all were in vain.

This is my models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="team_pictures")
    name= models.CharField(max_length=60)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    degree = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I know it is an easy fix but cant figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: how does your model look? show us the ImageField